# Peeking into an AJAX/HTTP call with Protractor/Webdriver? Have $HttpBackend return data sent to it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to spy on a $http/AJAX request made by the browser with Protractor/Webdriver?

Is there a way to have $http-backend return the request that was sent to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an HTTP interceptor. At first it was troublesome getting it to work, three different syntaxes all made element locators fail and selenium exit immediately. But then it worked on the next try. Here it is: it puts the data from the HTTP request into a `$rootScope` variable, which can then be asserted against with `.evaluate()`

```js
    var e2eInterceptors = function() {
      return angular.module('e2eInterceptors', ['yetiWonderland']).factory('loginInterceptor', function($rootScope) {
        return {
          request: function(config) {
            if (config.method === 'PUT'){
              $rootScope.testData = config.data;
              console.log("ROOTSCOPE!", $rootScope.testData);
            }
            configIntercept = config
            return config
          },
            response: function(response) {
            console.log("RESPONSE!");
            return response;
          },
        };
      }).config(function($httpProvider) {
        return $httpProvider.interceptors.push('loginInterceptor');
      });
    };
    browser.addMockModule('e2eInterceptors', e2eInterceptors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this might be what you need:

[NodeJS bindings for browsermob-proxy to programmatically generate HAR files](https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node)

Essentially you need a proxy server running, Selenium traffic sent through the proxy, and then a way (JavaScript bindings, REST API) to obtain a queriable [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) file that contains full details of all the HTTP requests and responses generated from your web request.

**Edit:**

A HAR file is just a JSON archive, so it shouldn't be too difficult to examine and query it from JavaScript. Here are a couple of Node libraries that may help:

- [JavaScript library to manipulate HTTP Archive 1.2 JSON objects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httparchive.js)
- [Extremely fast HTTP Archive (HAR) validator using JSON Schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/har-validator/)

Comment: Hmmm interesting suggestion. Can I query that file from within my test?

Comment: Would it be possible to have express send a response that my protractor test would pick up? This looks pretty involved. If I have to I might resort to this, but a simpler solution would be more desirable